# .width() not working in jQuery

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I want to do something like this in JQuery

```
if($(this).width() < 400px){
      //do something
}
```

But it didnt work like that....mhm how is it correct?

Comment: This is spelled out very clearly in the first sentence of the documentation. [http://api.jquery.com/width/](http://api.jquery.com/width/) please read here first next time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**`width()`**](http://api.jquery.com/width/) returns a plain number, and even if not your code would have an undefined symbol since `400px` is not in quotes - instead use it like this:

```
if($(this).width() < 400){
      //do something
}
```